# Log.d() stops working after calling Integer.parseInt(INVALID_INT)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat

```
private void someFunction(String html) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Element vol = doc.select(CSS_PATH).first();

    Log.d("Vol", vol.text());


    Log.d(TAG, "This gets printed");
    Float.parseFloat(vol.text());
    Log.d(TAG, "BUT THIS ONE NOT");
}
```

These two objects are elements of the Jsoup library.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element vol = doc.select(PATH.PEAK_DOWN_VOL).first();
```

`vol.text()` returns a `String` containing a float value.

```
Log.d("Vol", vol.text()); // logs something similar to 'Vol: 12.4'
```

But after calling `Float.parseFloat(peakDownVol.text());`, **`Log.d` in this class will stop entirely.** But `Log.d`'s in the Activity class seems to work just fine.

If I change `Float.parseFloat(vol.text());` to `Integer.parseInt(vol.text());`, it logs the subsequent statements without any problem.

I have lot of number parsing to do. So I'd like to know why is this happening exactly?

Comment: Your exception is probably getting caught higher in the call stack, effectively meaning the code following its generation is not executed.  Try catching the exception locally.

Comment: @ChrisStratton You were right. I was running the app whole time and not debugging it.

Comment: Running is fine - debugging isn't generally needed and just adds overhead and startup time (granted not to the same degree today as it did originally).  What you need is more attention to Java exception handling.

Comment: Post your stacktrace. How can we know what exception is thrown.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yeah, If I catch the exception locally I could see the problem. But I wonder why Android Studio does not warn me for any unhandle exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the rest of the method to run regardless, you should catch the potential exception locally, so that the program can continue executing the rest of the method and not bubble back up the call stack until it finds an exception handler or crashes for the lack of one:

```
Log.d(TAG, "This gets printed");
try {
   Float.parseFloat(vol.text());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   e.printStackTrace(); //leave evidence in the log
}
Log.d(TAG, "So does this");
```

Comment: Apparently it will also throw a NullPointerException if the argument is null.